# SSIS TransactionOption Required causes error (all on local machine)

Tags: transactions, ssis, distributed-transactions

I have seen a few posts related to my question but there are too many maybes which has prompted me to ask for a more direct solution.

Everything I am doing is on my local machine, although I am on a domain.

When I set a package's transaction option to required (and everything else inside to supported) my package no longer executes (in BIDS 2008).  I have the following error messages:

**Failed to get properties of external columns. The table name you entered may not exist, or you do not have SELECT permission on the table object and an alternative attempt to get column properties through connection has failed.**

Detailed error messages are: 
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
No column information is found for table [tablename] by querying System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

Error: 0xC004706B at Import Modulus Check, SSIS.Pipeline: "component "ADO NET Destination" (381)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error: 0xC004700C at Import Modulus Check, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.

Error: 0xC0024107 at Import Modulus Check: There were errors during task validation.

I have ensured the Distributed Transaction Coordinator Service has started but I am not really savvy with the configuration options so I suspect that is where my problem lies.

Does anyone know for certain exactly how this needs to be configured to have it working on my local machine?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, so I read somewhere the transaction services does not support ADO.NET connectors in SSIS.  Weird... but oh well, I changed them to OLEDB connections.  Now instead of erroring the execution just hangs....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the complications were due to a TRUNCATE command within the transaction.  If you are experiencing the same issue then all you need to do is set ValidateExternalMetadata to false on all your data connections (inside the transaction), or use the DELETE command instead.